# How to use HttpClient with proxy on Unity il2cpp build?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The code below works on editor and mono build, but not il2cpp build.

I found this bug report:
https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?1156595_buha3p1v4iq7vpv9

and noticed that developers have decided to not fix this issue.

So, is there any solutions on il2cpp build.
thanks

```
        if (Settings.GetBool_AndIsTrue("useSystemProxy"))
        {
            print("use System proxy");
            HttpClientHandler handler = new();
            handler.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
                                                   | SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                                   | (SecurityProtocolType)0x300 //Tls11 .net framework 4.0
                                                   | (SecurityProtocolType)0xC00; //Tls12 .net framework 4.0
            httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        }
 
        httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);
       
        string result = string.Empty;
        //first try
        try
        {
            result = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
        }
```

Comment: Use the Unity-equivalent instead of this _white-collar-dependency-injection-orientated_ class.  It's wishes to live in a singleton world is at odds with Unity and its [inability to detect DNS changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0#remarks) problematic.

Comment: hmm, I use UnityWebRequest instead. It seems ok now. thanks

Comment: No worries, `HttpClient` is an embarrassment.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I use UnityWebRequest instead. It seems ok now.
some code:

```
UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        req.timeout = 10;

        yield return req.SendWebRequest();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.error))
        {
             var objects = Json.ToObject<List<object>>(req.downloadHandler.text);
            string translation = "";

            var translationItems = (IEnumerable)objects[0];
            foreach (object item in translationItems)
            {
                IEnumerable translationLineObject = item as IEnumerable;

                IEnumerator translationLineString = translationLineObject.GetEnumerator();

                translationLineString.MoveNext();

                translation += $" {Convert.ToString(translationLineString.Current)}";
            }

            // Remove first blank character
            if (translation.Length > 1)
            {
                translation = translation[1..];
            }
            result.Add(translation);
        }
```